# Modify existing code for creating menu names in an interactive shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

When i give the command `awk NR==7 ABC.mod` it gives me the title ('Add') I need which is present on the 7th line of the file  Currently I am just able to read the title but I am not aware of how to append it to the output.  Can somebody help me organize this so I can modify the code to get the expected menu output with minimal disruption (I hope) to the existing script?

Comment: What's in ```pradee.sh```?  does each ```$up.sh```  have the same structure? We need more information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can pull out the "Add", "Delete" ... and other "titles" from the 7th line of each `*.mod` file, then you need to modify your script where it looks at the file `a1.out` somewhere before the line which *seems* to create the menu, namely: `tr ' ' '\n' < ~/a1.out > ~/b.dat`.

I say "assuming" because, even though you mention `awk NR==7`, I don't see where you are using it in the script. In any case, if you can get the "title" from the 7th line of a given `*.mod` file, then you can get the menu "name" from the file name (which seems to be the way you are constructing your menu) like this:

```
awk '{ln=length(ARGV[1]); if(NR==7) print substr(ARGV[1],0,ln-4)"..."$0}' ABC.mod
```

outputs:

```
ABC...Add
```

There's may be a shorter, easier way to do this using `sed`, but you mentioned `awk`.

For me at least, there's not really enough information to go on to help you much further. If you update your question someone may be able to give more concrete advice.

**EDIT:**
I'll post my work here in the hope that you find it useful.  It is not a complete solution. I have to say, this is a strangely written application - with shell code and variables hardwired to temporary data to locations strewn about the file system. It's a bit hairy to try and set up a local version to try it out. Hopefully by experimenting and making modifications to the cod e you will learn more about how your application works and about shell programming in general.  Extra advice: record your changes; sketch out how/where your application reads and writes its data; use comments in the source code to help you and others remember how the code works;  make backups; use source control.

My assumptions:

`pradee.sh` looks like this (why does the file has a `.sh` extension - it seems more like a it defines some constants for your script)

```
% cat pradee.sh 
HBKTM 
ABC 
HBKTM 
CBC 
HBKTM 
DBC
HBKTM 
IBC
HBKTM 
MBCE
HBKTM 
UBC
HBKTM
VBCM
```

Here's how I created my "test environment":

```
% for file in `grep -v HBKTM pradee.sh`; do touch $file.mod ; done
% ls
ABC.mod   CBC.mod   DBC.mod   IBC.mod   MBCE.mod  UBC.mod   VBCM.mod  pradee.sh    
% echo -e "_ctrl.jsp \n\n\n\n\n" > *.mod # mod files have required text+6 lines 
% echo -e "_ctrl.jsp \n\n\n\n\n" > HBKTM.mod  # this file seems special ?
% sed -i'' -e "7i\\[Ctrl-V Ctrl-J]
 Add" ABC.mod

OR since the files now have 6 lines ... echo the menu title onto the last line:

% echo "Delete" >> DBC.mod
% echo "Insert" >> IBC.mod
 ... [continue inserting titles like "Add" "Delete" etc to the other *.mod files]
```

After that I **think** I have data files that mimic your set up. You tell me.  Now, if I make a few small changes to your script (so the file locations don't remove overwrite my own files) and add the `awk` command I mentioned  previously, here is what I end up with:

```
# menu_create.sh                                                                                                                                           
# See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297671                           

rm -f *.dat                                                                     
clear                                                                           
cont="y"   

while [ "$cont" = "y" ] # "$" is need for POSIX                                 
do                                                                              
  echo -e "\n\nPlease Enter ONS Name : "                                        
  read ons                                                                      
  currpath=.                                                                    
  up=$(echo $ons|tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')                                    
  #echo "\n ONS menu name \n"                                                   
  #echo $up                                                                     
  if [ -f $up.mod ]; then                                                       
    #in=$(grep -ri $up pradee.sh) # changed to following                        
    # - how could this have worked ?                                                                            
    in=$(grep -v $up pradee.sh)                                               
    if [ -n "$in" ]; then                                                       
        onsname=$(grep -ri "_ctrl.jsp" $up.mod)                                 
        #echo "onsname : $onsname"                                              
            if [ -n "$onsname" ]; then                                          
              echo -e "\n ONS menu name : $up "                           
              echo $in > a1.dat                                               
              #echo "written to a1.dat\n"                                 
              #cat ~/a1.dat                                                   
              #tr ' ' '\n' < ~/a1.dat > ~/a.dat                               
              #cat ~/a.dat                                                    
              sed "s/$up//g" a1.dat >a1.out                                   
              for i in `cat  a1.dat`; 
              do 
              awk '{ln=length(ARGV[1]);if(NR==7) print substr(ARGV[1],0,ln-4)"..."$0}' $i.mod >> menu.dat ; 
              done
                echo -e "\n FINUX Names \n"                                     
                #tr ' ' '\n' < a1.out > b.dat                                   
                tr ' ' '\n' < menu.dat > b.dat                                  
                cat b.dat                                                       
            else                                                            
                echo -e "ONS Name Not Valid !"                              
              fi                                                            
    else                                                                    
        echo -e "FINUX menu Name not found in our Repository"               
    fi                                                                      
  else                                                                      
    echo -e "\n Please Enter valid ONS name !!"                             
  fi                                                                        
  echo -e "\n\n Press "y" to continue, Any other key to exit"               
  read cont                                                                 
done
```

It gives me this output:

```
Please Enter ONS Name : 
hbktm

 ONS menu name : HBKTM 

 FINUX Names 

ABC...Add
CBC...Cancel
DBC...Delete
IBC...Insert
MBCE...Modify
UBC...Undelete
VBCM...Verify


 Press y to continue, Any other key to exit
q
```

I hope my response to your question helps you learn more about how to modify your application.

Comment: This is not really the way you should be using StackExchange.  It's still not clear from your comments to me what the format of pradee.sh is and how it is used to set up your menu.  Are you trying to find out *where* in your script to add the `awk` commands that will do this?

Comment: If the only thing you are using the ```*mod``` files for is to get the name from the 7th line, then  the command I gave you earlier to modify the menu should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! I have sorted out the issue and ur command worked ... Simply Awesum Cito !!!!!!!!! Thanks once again..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32548/discussion-between-user2519862-and-g-cito)